# Use C to generate dynamic HTML in iPad app?

Tags: html, c, xcode

I'm working on an iPad app that has a several complex tables I think might be best represented as HTML tables, except the data's all dynamic (variable number of columns and rows and cell contents). Since the rest of the app is all in C, is it possible to embed C in UIWebView to generate the dynamic content? Otherwise, I suppose I'll have to use JavaScript and live with a two code app.  I don't think Table View is flexible enough, at least with my rudimentary xCode skills.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't the iPad use Objective C?

Comment: The iPad works fine with ANSI C which our flight calculations are all written in.  C works fine on the iPad for 90 percent of the code. My question is can C, or Obj C, be embedded in a UIWebView to generate dynamic HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`loadHTMLString:buffer baseURL:nil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a) to load in dynamically generated HTML. It would only be as difficult as you make it. In the simplest case, for each table you add `<table>` to the buffer, then for each row add the `<tr>` tags and for each column within the row add your `<td>` and print the data for that cell. At the end of each for loop print the appropriate end tags. The code will be as complex as you want the table to be.

Comment: Sounds good.  If I understand what you're saying I generate the dynamic HTML in C building an .html file line-by-line, and then load it from UIWebView using the LoadHTMLString.  Correct?

Comment: Pretty much, but your ".html file" is just an NSString. Of course, you'll have to use some Objective-C to create the UIWebView and call the method, but I'm not exactly sure how that exactly meshes with your 90% C app.

Comment: I used Tozar's suggestions to build my html is c++, convert it over to  an NSString and running [_myWebview loadHTMLString:cppGeneratedHtml baseUrl:nil]… worked like a charm. thanks!